# creating a perodic triangle waveform with phase shift

Tags: matlab, octave, formula

I can create a periodic triangle waveform by changing the variable `freq` but how can I have the triangle waveform start at `t=0` with an upward going slope like a sine wave.  I was trying to figure out something like the sine wave equation [image: Sine wave equation] but basically for triangle waveforms.  Does something like this exist?

where:

[image: Text]

Code below:

```
t=linspace(0,2*pi,1000);
freq=2; %how many in 1 sec
A = 1; % amplitude
T = 2*pi/freq; % period of the signal

% triangle
figure(1);
triangle = (mod(t * A / T, A) > 0.5).*mod(t * A / T, A) + (mod(t * A / T, A) <= 0.5).*(1 - mod(t * A / T, A));
triangle = 2*triangle - 1.5;
plot(t, triangle);
title('triangle');
```

[image: What the code it looks like]

**PS:  I'm using octave 4.0 which is like matlab.**

Comment: Do you also know `sawtooth` from the signal processing toolbox? http://www.technoburst.net/2011/06/matlab-programs-04-generating.html --> If you want it to start downwards, just invert it. And if you want it to be symmetric around `y=0`, then simple substract an offset.

Comment: @tim thanks that helped a lot.  if you make your comment an answer I'll mark it is solved.

Comment: and btw, GNU Octave is not "like Matlab". Octave is free software

Comment: @Andy ok Andy I'll bite .... should I say "similar to matlab" instead :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you also know `sawtooth` from the signal processing toolbox?  Have a look [here](http://www.technoburst.net/2011/06/matlab-programs-04-generating.html) for a good example.

--> If you want it to start downwards, just invert it. And if you want it to be symmetric around y=0, then simple substract/add an offset.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the final code in case someone else needs to do this

```
clear all
figure(1);
freq=2
fs=1000;
t2=linspace(0,2*pi,fs);
phase_shift=pi/2; %phase shift
tri_w_phase=sawtooth(freq*t2+phase_shift,.5);
plot(t2,tri_w_phase)
title('triangle with freq edit and phase shift');
```